# Find the exact values of x so that $0 ≤ x < 2π$ and $\cos(x) = \sin(2x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the exact values of $x$ so that $0 ≤ x < 2π$ and $\cos(x) = \sin(2x)$.

I changed it to $\cos(x) = \sin(x)\cos(x) - \cos(x)\sin(x)$.

Not sure how I am going to get the value.

Comment: Note that $\sin(2x) = 2\sin x\cos x$.

Comment: It's appreciated (particularly for a user of your "age" on site) to [format your answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 3):

The double angle identity for sine is $\sin(2x) = 2\sin x\cos x$.  Thus,
\begin{align*}
\cos x & = \sin(2x)\\
\cos x & = 2\sin x\cos x\\
0 & = 2\sin x\cos x - \cos x\\
0 & = \cos x(2\sin x - 1)
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\cos x & = 0 & 2\sin x - 1 & = 0\\
& & 2\sin x & = 1\\
& & \sin x & = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

Can we use computer software here? Anyway, you can verify your solution with the code, e.g., in MuPad,

```
solve(cos(x)=sin(2*x),x=0..2*pi)
```

It spits out the result,

$\left(\left\{\left. \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\, \pi\, k \right| k\in\mathbb Z\right\} \cup \left\{\left. \frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{2\, \pi\, k}{3} \right| k\in\mathbb Z\right\}\right) \cap \left[0, 2\, \mathrm{pi}\right]$.

---

The correct code should be

```
solve(cos(x)=sin(2*x),x=0..2*PI)
```

It gives the solution within $[0,2\pi]$,

$\left\{\frac{3\, \pi}{2},\frac{5\, \pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{6}\right\}$

Comment: This misses the solution $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$. Are you sure MuPad did not give $\{\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k\}$?

Comment: Oh, this is terrible! To use computer programs to solve such easy, basic stuff? Come on...not to mention it is usualy, fortunately, not even considered in most high schools and universities I know...in fact, in **none** that I know of.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, you are right. I'd use the computer program to do sanity check.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales $\frac{3\pi}2 = \frac{\pi}6+2\times\frac{2\pi}3$, which is included in the computer solution.

Comment: Correct. My bad.